# How to use mahout for association rule mining(i.e. Market Basket Annalysis)?

Tags: mahout

I want to implement an item recommender from frequent items patterns. I want to perform it using Apache Mahout (on Distribted Environment). 
Is there any algorithm in Mahout which can help to generate patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A frequent pattern mining algorithm used to be part of Mahout, but has since been removed. There is a whole blog post [here](https://datasciencehacks.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/market-basket-analysis-with-mahout/) explaining how to implement Market Basket Analysis with Mahout using the "mahout fpg" command. Be sure to use Mahout 0.7 though, because it was removed after that. You can also read more about it on the Mahout website: http://mahout.apache.org/users/misc/parallel-frequent-pattern-mining.html